# Inserting and editing user reviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a review system which lets users create reviews for films, and, if they try to add another review for the same film it updates their previous one. The update is done through the `create` method in the review controller.

I'm trying to use this in films show page. Currently users can add a review by choosing the "add review" option on the show page of a film which is always there. If they have written a review for that particular film before by choosing 'add review' their previous review is still updated. What I want to do is to display a button saying "edit review" if they have written a review before and "add review" if they haven't. Any ideas?

review controller - create:

```
def create    
@review = Review.find_or_create_by_film_id_and_name(params[:review][:film_id],        
User.find(session[:user_id]).name)
@review.update_attributes(params[:review])
if @review.save
film = Film.find(@review.film.id)
redirect_to film, notice: 'Your review was successfully added.'
else
render action: "new"
end
end
```

review controller - new:

```
def new
if logged_in?
@review = Review.new(:film_id => params[:id], :name =>     
User.find(session[:user_id]).name)
session[:return_to] = nil 
else
session[:return_to] = request.url 
redirect_to login_path, alert: " 'You need to login to write a review' "
end
end
```

film show page:

```
<%= button_to 'Add Review',{controller: 'reviews', action: 'new', id: @film.id },
{class: "button-to"}%>
```

Comment: TBH it's probably better to say "You've already reviewed this. If you'd like to edit your current review, click here"

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below:

In `show` action of controller:

```
 def show
   @current_user_review = Review.find_by_film_id_and_name(film_id, user_name)
   #your stuff
 end

 def edit
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
   render 'new'
 end
```

In `view`:

```
 <% if @current_user_review.blank? %>
   <%= link_to 'Add Review',new_review_path(film_id: @film.id),
      {class: "button-to"}  %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit Your Review', edit_review_path(@current_user_review), {class: "button-to"} %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: = link_to 'Add Review', new_review_path(film_id: @film.id)
= link_to 'Edit Your View, edit_review_path(@current_user_review)

Comment: Ya you can use route paths as Bijan metioned

Comment: i keep getting both add review and edit review options available on the show page. not sure that the '@current_user_review' is working properly

Comment: just to confirm that @current_user_review should go in the reviews controller right? im trying to show the links 'add review' and 'edit review' on the film show page not the review.

Comment: Not in reviews controller.. It should be in show page of filmscontroller or whatever controller u have. But its impossible to show both. Because we are using `if..else`. It should show only one.

Comment: ok lol i forgot the else clause, and its not liking the (film_id, user_name). Is it possible that you gotta write a semicolon infront i.e. :film_id also the film model is not connected to the user model so im guessing thats why it doesn't like user_name

Comment: I just mentioned the fields what to be there. You need to put relevant code for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if @current_user_review.blank?%>
   <%= link_to_function("Create New Review", "$('create').toggle()") %>
<%else%>
   <%= link_to_function("To edit Review, Click here", "$('Edit').toggle()") %>
```

```
<div id="create" style="display: none;">
   <%= render :partial => "new" %> 
</div>

<div id="Edit" style="display: none;">
   <%=render :partial => edit %> # The new partial can also be be used here.
</div>
```

Comment: Whats this `link_to_function` does?

Comment: It creates an onclick event - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html